# Question editor toolbar is vertically aligned in Chromium 27

Tags: bug

The question editor toolbar is now vertically aligned instead of horizontal.

[image: Top screenshot editing this question]
[image: Roughly next area below that editing this question]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify your issue. I assume you're talking about the Ask Ubuntu page, right? Which editor? Comment? Question? Answer? What browser? What operating system?

Comment: You can manually upload an image at https://imgur.com and paste it like that: `![DESCRIPTION](URL)`

Comment: it's possible that you've zoomed in so far you can't see the submit button. Hitting CTRL- repeatedly will zoom out and CTRL+ repeatedly will zoom in in in most if not all browsers (firefox, chrome, ....)

Comment: Sorry for delay in response. Problem only occurs with Ask Question. Entering comments works fine. Browser is Chromium 27 on 32bit Linux. Cleared cache, disabled all extensions, logged back in and tried Ask Question again. Same behavior. Maybe CSS Grid vs Flex? Chromium 27 doesn't support Grid well (at all?). Hope to get new computer this year so can upgrade. Thanks.

Comment: @DocSalvager Chromium **27**? I doubt they support versions that old. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/270345 Also, even 14.04 has 34+.

Comment: @muru, This is more to advise than anything else. Though well beyond the supported versions, past changes that broke these old browsers have usually been fixed when they were made aware of them and the fix was easy enough. Graceful degredation is always preferred if possible.